# 4k Display appears smaller than Thunderbolt Display

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display, 4k

I have 2 displays connected to my Mac. 1 27" Dell 4k Display and a 27" Apple Thunderbolt Display.

Since both are 27", while the dell is 4k and the Thunderbolt display is 2k I would imagine the thunderbolt display appearing as the smaller display under display settings.

[image]

However, the thunderbolt display appears to be the larger display under display settings.
And the windows appear significantly smaller when I move a window from the 4k dell to the thunderbolt display.

Why is that?

Comment: I had a double-take on the answer below. If you can check whether it is in fact scaling-related, we can turn it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this, as I only have one Retina display in an iMac, my main screens [on another Mac] are all 2k.
I think this is going to be governed by the Scaling in Displays - our iMac gives this for the retina display…

[image]

My 2k displays do not… they have the old style resolution structure

[image]

Check what 'zoom' you're using on the 4k screen. I think this may be the deciding factor.

---

*below applies to non-retina screens*

You need to look at the resolution, not the physical size.

The Displays pref pane does not consider the physical display size, only its resolution. [It has this information available to it, but it is not used].

Your Dell is running at full 4k - 3840x2160; the Apple at 2k - 2560x1440. This is what Displays looks at.

You will also discover you cannot pass the cursor from one to the other anywhere they do not 'meet' in the displays arrange page.

Comment: Yes you're right. It has to do with the scaling on the Dell monitor. It was set to 'Default for Display'. Switching to 'Scaled'. Switching to the second-largest option made both displays appear as being the same size. Thank you!